# Module scope in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am having a hard time figuring out how this following module scope works in node.js.

**main.js**

```
module.exports = App = {
  add: function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

var getNumber = require('./module');
var result = App.add(100, getNumber());
```

**module.js**

```
var number = 200;

module.exports = function () {
  console.log(App); // App is visible here - how come?
  return number;
};
```

I wonder why App is visible in the module, since it is not required in. If I no longer export App, it is not visible.

Comment: You've just seen how careful you have to be with global variables. You can cause massive havoc in a node.js app if you're not very careful with global vars. Most people will tell you not to use them. If you do use them, you've got to be very, very careful.

Comment: Excluding 'var' is then similar to global.var?

Comment: That's a good question, for which I'm not certain of the answer, but I would believe it's yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't declare `var App`, `App` became a global variable implicitly. This happens even if you don't have `module.exports` at all.

Answer (score 1):

`App` is on the Global Scope:

```js
foo = {}

foo.bar = baz = 5

console.log(baz)

// baz is available on the global scope
```